Cannot use Brother MFC-L8610CDW printer on Kubuntu 24.04
I have a Brother MFC-L8610CDW printer.  The printer works fine on Windows, but I cannot make it work from Linux.
My primary machine is running Kubuntu 22.04 LTS, but I have the same problems with other machines running 22.04 LTS.  I have included the version information for the primary machine at the end of this post.
I have tried so many things that it's hard to summarize everything.  Here are the key points:
I have tried using the drivers included with Linux.
I have tried downloading the latest driver deb packages from Brother.
I have tried connecting to the printer directly.
I have tried connecting over WiFi, and also over Ethernet.
I have tried sharing the printer from Windows and connecting via SMB (it works from the Windows machine, and jobs from the Linux machine never appear in the Windows print queue).
I have tried on 3 different Linux machines, all with the same results.
The frustrating part is that I cannot get it to give me any kind of error message.  It just fails.  Sometimes I can get the Printers page in System Settings to install the printer, but most of the time, after I hit "Finish" installing the printer, it just never shows up as an installed printer.  In cases where I get the printer to show up as installed (which I cannot seem to do anymore), any attempts to print appear to do nothing at all.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can systematically diagnose the problem?  Without any error messages, it's just been trial and error, and I'm about out of things to try.  At this point, the Printers page in System Settings show no printers installed, and I can't even get the installation to succeed anymore.  As I mentioned, the installation Wizard runs fine, but after hitting "Finish", no printer is ever added.
Thanks,
-Wade
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-31-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 32 × Intel® Core™ i9-14900KF
Memory: 125.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2
Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: Z790 AORUS ELITE X WIFI7
System Version: -CF

Did you download and execute the installer tool found in linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.3-1.gz

After extracting the tool from the gz file, you would need to first switch to a root shell: sudo su and then, in the same directory as the extracted installer file, run linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.3-1 MFC-L8610CDW And after you are finished, don't forget to exit out of your root shell: exit

I guess maybe that's the installer Wizard you mention?

Did you already try this solution?

I was able to get it working this morning by running the linux-brprinter-installer tool.  This is not the first time that I have tried it.  I ran it several times this morning with different parameters for the device URI prompt.  I was only able to get it to work by answering "n" to the "Will you specify the Device URI" prompt.
Thanks for the suggestions.
PS:  This was not the "wizard" that I referenced.  What I meant by "wizard" is the sequence of UI prompts that happen when you click the "Add Printer" button in "Printers - System Settings".

Does this answer your question? Brother printer does not work after installation

Okay. I voted to close as a duplicate because the accepted answer for that question is to run the command line brother installer.
